# Doesn't "go get" just fetch files and then cgo+"go build" them? Apparently not

Tags: gcc, windows-7, mingw, go, cgo

I have a problem building a fairly simple local CGO project. Consider [this very small CGO package](https://github.com/zombiezen/Go-GLUT/tree/master/glut) of just 3 files (glut.go, support.c and support.h file) -- if I just **go get** it, these files are downloaded to

```
C:\Go\src\pkg\github.com\zombiezen\Go-GLUT\glut
```

then some secret magic happens and **go get** builds the following output file:

```
C:\Go\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\zombiezen\Go-GLUT\glut.a
```

However, if I copy the three source files to \mytmp, cd into \mytmp and **go build -o glut.a glut.go**, I get some 40-60 error messages like this one:

```
C:\Users\roxor\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build191975110\command-line-arguments\_obj\glut.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_b46885fb7c57_Cfunc_goCreateMenu':
./glut.go:195: undefined reference to `goCreateMenu'
```

If I run **go get** with the **-x** command-line argument, I can see that *support.c* is picked up during the build process and given to gcc:

```
gcc -I . -g -O2 -m64 -mthreads -I $WORK\github.com\zombiezen\Go-GLUT\glut\_obj\ -o $WORK\github.com\zombiezen\Go-GLUT\glut\_obj\support.o -c .\support.c
```

However, with **go build -x**, this is not the case, support.c is skipped. Why? How do I call **go build** to work exactly like **go get** does?

Comment: SOLVED. Just doing "go build" instead of "go build somefile.go" does it. So obvious now... how could I miss that?

Case closed.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it rather than leaving it as a comment, that way it is marked as accepted rather than 'Unanswered'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just doing `go build` instead of `go build somefile.go` does it. So obvious now …